# How can I see the juju-core debug-log without tailing it?

Tags: juju

I wanted to watch my env get deployed using the debug-log command

```
juju debug-log
```

But I forgot, so now my env is deployed so tailing the log is useless.

Where can I find the full log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to the bootstrap node

```
juju ssh 0
```

You can find it here

```
/var/log/juju/all-machines.log
```

Comment: That file does not contain anything on my bootstrap node. I deployed using juju-deployer. Does that change anything?

Comment: It shouldn't do, is there anything in your /var/log/juju or /var/lib/juju directories?